# Como fazer efeito ''tremendo'' com css

Tags: css

Seguinte, estou querendo obter um efeito com css mas não faço a mínima ideia de como fazer isso. O efeito é "tremendo", quando clica num input por exemplo, ele treme.

Sendo mais detalhado, o input tá lá, parado. Ao clicar nele (onclick ou onfocus) ele dá uma pequena tremidinha, mas não treme permanente, ele treme e logo para.

Como posso fazer isso? Só css resolve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagino que desejava algo como isto:

```css
input:focus {
  animation: treme 0.1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 3;
}

@keyframes treme {
  0% {margin-left: 0;}
  25% {margin-left: 5px;}
  50% {margin-left: 0;}
  75% {margin-left: -5px;}
  100% {margin-left: 0;}
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Basta usar uma [*css animation*](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Usando_anima%C3%A7%C3%B5es_CSS) no `:focus`.
O intervalo de vibração pode ser definida aumentado a variação, no caso, uso o `margin-left` variando de **-5px** a **+5px**. Além disso, podes definir o número de vibrações com o `animation-iteration-count`.

Comment: Caraca, algo tão simples e não pensei em animation... 
Valeu cara!

Comment: @GabrielMoodlight, de nada ^.